# Persistence mechanism used by Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon

1. Is orbeon using JDBC or any other ORM technique to persist the data.
2. I have downloaded the orbeon CE source code from GitHub provided by Orbeon. It would be better if someone suggested me the code flow of Orbeon Forms.

Answer (score 0):

> Is orbeon using JDBC or any other ORM technique to persist the data.

JDBC yes, ORM no.

For details on the tables, see the links to the DLL in [database setup](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html#database-setup.)

> I have downloaded the orbeon CE source code from GitHub provided by Orbeon. It would be better if someone suggested me the code flow of Orbeon Forms.

That would be way beyond the scope of a simple StackOverflow question.